# Set Gmail as the default `mailto:` email client in Arc browser

Tags: email, google-chrome, gmail, macos

How can I make the (Chrome-based) Arc browser handle `mailto:` links by opening a Gmail compose view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Log into Gmail at least once from the current space/browser profile.
2. In the URL bar, type `chrome://settings`.
3. Navigate to **Privacy and security > Site settings**.
4. Under **Permissions**, click on **Additional permissions**.
5. Click **Protocol handlers**.
6. Next to mail.google.com, click the three-dot menu (**⋮**) and select **Set as default**.

When you click your next `mailto:` link, a Gmail compose view will open within a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I had to [go a bit deeper to get this working](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/getting-gmail-to-handle-all-mailto-links-with-registerprotocolhandler/). TLDR:

1. Open up a Gmail tab
2. Open JS console (cmd-opt-j on    Mac, ctrl-shift-j on Windows)
3. Enter:
       `navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto",    "https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s", "Gmail");`
4. Accept the confirmation from the browser
5. Try a mailto: link and see if it worked!

For some reason, the Protocol handlers setting page always showed Gmail as a disabled handler. Even when I removed it and went back to Gmail, Arc wouldn't ask - it was just set as disabled again.

After removing from Arc again, following those instructions worked for me.

Comment: I needed to remove Gmail from `arc://settings/handlers` first before running this code snippet. It worked, but it's kind of weird. It doesn't show me my own (the sender's) email (I have multiple Gmail accounts logged in). It also doesn't open in an already open gmail tab, but I guess that's asking too much.